# Implementing countdown in django in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have a bootstrap template where the countdown is already implemented. And the time is hardcoded like below.

```
<div  data-countdown="2020/03/01"></div>
```

here, if I change the number like 2020 it shows the calculated time. But I didn't want this hardcoded time or number. I want to put my actual time from my DateTime fields. So how can I use my DateTime variable as a template variable and put it as the parameter of the data-countdown attribute above?  Like we do with {{}} .

Comment: What makes you think that it would work differently than with any other template var???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the django template filter like this

```
<div data-countdown="{{ datetime_from_context|date:"Y/m/d" }}"></div>
```

Use this as a reference incase if you want to change the format:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/references/2016/06/21/date-filter.html

Answer (score 1):

You could put the dates from your datetime fields into the context of the view rendering this page and access them in the template using `{{}}`

```
def some_view(request):
    # get your dates here, assuming from some model object
    date = "some date you got"
    return render(request, 'app/template_name.html', {'countdown_date': date}
```

In the template

```
<div data-countdown="{{countdown_date}}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say that the value of your `DateTimeField` is `datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 28, 12, 36, 56, 310538)`. So You can get the date in your view by:

```py
def your_view(request):
    some_date_time_obj = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 28, 12, 36, 56, 310538)
    date_from_date_time = some_date_time_obj.date() # will return datetime.date(2020, 1, 28)
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'date': data})
```

In your template, you can set that value by:

```html
<div  data-countdown="{{ date }}"></div>
```

If you want date in `YYYY/MM/DD` format then you can call `strftime()` method like this:

```py
date_from_date_time = some_date_time_obj.date().strftime('%Y/%m/%d') # will return '2020/01/28'
```